# php "include" is ignoring all code and outputting code on page

Tags: php

I am making a search engine that searches through a file, and every time it outputs the results, every other code in the page doesn't work.

search.php:

```
<form action="" method="GET" name="">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="q" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : ''; ?>" placeholder="" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="" value="search" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<body>
<?php
include("results.php");
?>
</body>
```

results.php:

```
<?php
$file = 'test.txt';
$searchfor = $_GET['q'];

// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');

// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";

// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches))
{
   echo "Found matches:\n";
   echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
}
else
{
   echo "No matches found";
}
```

and then when it goes through results.php, it outputs this on my localhost site, not my code editor:

```
<form action="" method="GET" name="">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="q" value="dawn" placeholder="" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="" value="search" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<body>
Found matches:
dawn
</body>
```

Does anybody know what's causing this output?

I've tried googling a lot, but I can't find anything.

Comment: `// the following line prevents the browser from parsing this as HTML.
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
`

Comment: You include it in search.php, so it runs in search.php therefore search.php sends a plain text response.

Comment: @ArleighHix Actually it should be causing a `Headers already sent` error, since he outputs HTML in `search.php` before the `include` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `header()` one another in files. Change files like that.

**Content of search.php**

```php
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html');
?>
<form action="" method="GET" name="">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="q" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : ''; ?>" placeholder="" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="" value="search" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<body>
<?php
include("results.php");
?>
</body>
```

**Content of results.php**

```php
<?php
$file = 'test.txt';
$searchfor = $_GET['q'];


// get the file contents, assuming the file to be readable (and exist)
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

// escape special characters in the query
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');

// finalise the regular expression, matching the whole line
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";

// search, and store all matching occurences in $matches
if (preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches))
{
   echo "Found matches:\n";
   echo htmlspecialchars(implode("\n", $matches[0]));
}
else
{
   echo "No matches found";
}
```